# Вместо загрузки обновлений на удалённый сервер с gitHub получаю: Already up to date

Tags: ubuntu, git, github

Друзья быть может кто поможет, уже почти отчаился пытаюсь загрузить обновления с репозитория на удалёный сервер командой: `git pull origin main`, но вместо этого получаю сообщение: Already up to date. А структура проекта остаётся без имзенений. Как быть, уже 2 часа сижу бьюсь с этой проблемой и до 3 ночи уже сидел и никакого сдвига

Comment: Значит состояние выбранной ветки в склонированном репозитории и в origin совпадает.

Comment: `pull` — это обновление локального репозитория из удалённого.

Comment: Может тебе нужен git push?

Comment: `pull` *(eng)* = вытянуть ; `push` *(eng)* = вытолкать